# MongoDB - taking more time for the First fetch than SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

I'am using mongodb in my project to reduce the time, While comparing the time taken for fetching data from SQL and NoSQL, SQL takes 50ms for each fetch form database but NoSQL takes around 180ms for first time and 15ms for other fetches, how to reduce the fetching time for the first time in NoSQL.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the amount of data, number of documents and the query (how you are fetching the document)?

Comment: You need to tell us what queries you are running if you expect us to tell you how to speed them up...

Comment: @amit_saxena My collection has 108 records. I used the below query to fetch the records. `IMongoQuery query = new QueryDocument(); query = Query.And(query, Query.EQ("Field1", 1)); MongoCollection<BsonDocument> collectionAC = MongoDBs.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("CollectionName");
var Log = collectionAC.FindAs<BsonDocument>(query).SetFields(Fields.Exclude(dyFields)).ToList();`

Comment: @Sammaye This was my document structure. `{  "AC" : { "A_C_N" : "work","Ast_File_Name" : "untitled.bmp",
    "A_Sts" : 0, "A_Active" : "True",
    "M_Size" : -1, "S_Descr" : "description"  },
  "AC_Sk" : 20,
  "Asts" : [{  "Ast_Name" : "Testing" }],
  "_id" : ObjectId("51aa93ee6f1f9a0bbcab0886") }`

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an index for your collection to make queries run faster

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/

Comment: @Gavruk I have given indexing with unique: ture already. My query takes that time for the first time of fetching only.

Comment: Maybe your data is not loaded to the memory. After the first query, MongoDB loads your data to the memory and next queries become work faster

Answer (score 0):

The first query is probably taking more time because it loads the working set into your RAM. Details about working set can be found here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/#what-is-the-working-set

To avoid this problem you may want to pre-load this before any of your actual users hit the database. One way I can think of is an hourly (or any frequency you find suitable) cron that does this query each hour to load the working set into memory, for faster subsequent queries.

Comment: Hi @amit, do I need to add any config setting in my config file,`dbpath,logpath and logappend` this was the settings given right now in my config. what I have to do for making my db to load its working set into RAM.

Comment: As I said, you can have a periodic cronjob that fires similar query and loads the working set into RAM.

Comment: Hi @amit, as you said I made the same query in another page load(i.e, given same query in page_1.aspx) , even though the selection for my page (i.e, current_page .aspx) takes more time for first time as it done in page_1.aspx. what might be the problem, please guide me to proceed time was my criteria.

Comment: Hi @amit, also for your reference I have give the code below which I used. Please do the needful for reducing the fetching time.

Comment: Below was the code  `public string GAST(){string json = "";var Logs = new List<BsonDocument>();IMongoQuery query = new QueryDocument();string[] dyFlds = new string[] { "_id", "Asts.UId"};query = Query.And(query, Query.EQ("AC", AC));MongoDBs.RequestStart();MongoCollection<BsonDocument> collectionAC =   MongoDBs. GetCollection <BsonDocument>("AstC");Logs = collectionAC.FindAs<BsonDocument>query).SetFields(Fields.Exclude(dyFlds)). ToList();if (Logs.Count != 0){ BsonDocument doc= Logs[0];json = docAsset[0].ToString();}MongoDBs.RequestDone();return json;}`